# SpringBoot Thymeleaf cannot find CSS

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

I have a problem with spring-boot-thymeleaf 2.7.10 version. The problem is that thymeleaf cannot find CSS for specified template.
File stucture is

```
|  +--static/
|  |  +--css/
|  +--templates/
|  |  +--mail/
|  |  |
```

TemplateEngine configuration is

```
@Bean
public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
    SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setApplicationContext(this.applicationContext);
    templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    templateResolver.setPrefix("classpath:/templates/mail/");
    templateResolver.setCacheable("classpath:/templates/mail/".startsWith("classpath:/"));
    return templateResolver;
}
```

When i try to import css file in my HTML template by using

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" th:href="@{/css/styles.css}" href="../../../../../static/css/styles.css">
```

I got an error

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Link base "/css/styles.css" cannot be context relative (/...) unless the context used for executing the engine implements the org.thymeleaf.context.IWebContext interface
```

I saw that many answer in stackOverwlow recommends to use definition like that but in doesnt work for me.
How can i properly import css into thymeleaf template?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sending this in an email?

You can't use `context relative` links in this case -- which is the error shown in your question.  What do you think would happen when a user opens this email in gmail and the browser tries to resolve `mail.google.com/css/styles.css`?

You must either use an absolute link to your css, or include the entire body of the css in your email.